# image to base64 ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, base64

Anyone knows what the route is in TS, so that it takes an image and transforms it to base64? Is it to share a local image on Facebook?

regards.

This is my function code:

```
share(){



let filePath: string = "file:///assets/imgs/pesa4.jpg";

let shreface = this.actioSheetController.create({

  buttons:[
    {
      text:"facebook",
      icon:"logo-facebook",
      handler:()=>{
        this.base64.encodeFile(filePath).then((myBase64: string) => {
        this.socialSharing.share(this.message, this.subject, myBase64, this.url)
        console.log(myBase64);
        })
      }
    }
  ]

});
shreface.present(); 
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKBe7.png)

Comment: What exactly is your question? This code above should work, right?

Comment: this directory "file:///assets/imgs/pesa4.jpg" isn´t correct, i need te correct directory of imgs in Typescript

Answer (score 0):

Try with `assets/imgs/pesa4.jpg` remove `"file:///"`

If you want to convert local storage image to base64 use file and file chooser plugin.

Comment: I need transform local folder image, Dont local storage! Thanks sudhakar.